# How to show different dates data (from the same table) as columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm sorry if the title wasn't too clear, but the following explanation will be more accurate.

I have the following view:

```
DATE          USER         CONDITION
20140101      1            A
20140101      2            B
20140101      3            C
20140108      1            C
20140108      3            B
20140108      2            C
```

What I need to do is present how many users where in all conditions this week and 7 days before today.

Output should be like this:

```
Condition          Today          Last_Week (Today-7)
A                  0              1
B                  1              1
C                  2              1
```

How can I do this in Oracle? I will need to do this for 4 weeks so itll be Today-7,14-21.

I've tried this with group by but I get the "week2" as rows. Then I've tried something like `Select conditions, (select count(users) from MyView where DATE='Today') FROM MyView`(looking at something thats actually working) but it doesnt work for me.

Achieved this with a little modification of the accepted answer:

```
select condition, 
   count(case when to_date(xdate) = to_date(sysdate) then 1 end) to_day,
   count(case when to_date(xdate) = to_date(sysdate-7) then 1 end) last_7_days
from my_table
group by condition
```

Comment: It seems that can be done with a groupby/aggregations, so what have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, I've done it with group by but I get the "week2" as rows. Then I've tried something like `Select conditions, (select count(users) from MyView where DATE='Today') FROM MyView` (looking at something thats actually working) but it doesnt work for me. :/

Comment: @rhyuk it's always benefical to include your attempts in question, as 1) along with helping you to solve your task you may expect get comments and fixes to your attemts, that will help you better understand something  2) questions demonstrating some work done before asking have more value and tend to attract more good answers.

Comment: @alko thanks! Will include what I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select condition, count(case when to_date(xdate) = to_date(sysdate) then 1 end) to_day,
       count(case when to_date(xdate) < to_date(sysdate) then 1 end) last_7_days
  from my_table
 where to_date(xdate) >= to_date(sysdate) - 7
 group by condition
```

Comment: Are you counting all the cases between a period of time (Day 1 to Day 7) or just a specific date?

Comment: All of them, I selected last 7 days plus today events (using where clause), and then counted today events in one, and others in another.

Comment: I must not add all seven days. I must count the conditions for that specific date. Like conditions for today (20140108) and conditions for last week (20140101). Nothing in between.

Comment: `sysdate` already returns value of `date` data type, no need to use `to_date()` function. Moreover, it might have side effects because of double data type conversion and current NLS settings. When you are converting a literal whether it's a number or a character one to a `date` using `to_date()` function it's always a good idea to specify date format mask (in this particular situation it would be `yyyymmddd` )

Comment: Achieved what I needed to do with a little modification of Amir's suggestion.

`select condition, 
    count(case when to_date(xdate) = to_date(sysdate) then 1 end) to_day,
       count(case when to_date(xdate) = to_date(sysdate) then 1 end) last_7_days
 from my_table
 group by condition`

Answer (score 0):

```
select condition
,      sum
       ( case
         when date between trunc(sysdate) - 7 and trunc(sysdate) - 1
         then 1
         else 0
         end
       )
       last_week
,      sum
       ( case
         when date between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate + 1)
         then 1
         else 0
         end
       )
       this_week
from   table
group
by     condition
```

By using the conditional count (as a sum) and grouping on condition you can filter out all desired dates. Note that using trunc will cause to use the begin of the day.

Comment: And where did 24 came from? And `sysdate - 7 * 24` will result 168 days before sysdate!!

Comment: It will count today events in last week events, which is not what asked in the question.

Comment: Sorry. Mixed up systems. Answer should be ok now

Comment: Provide some additional explanation to your answer please.